# How to draw graphs like this?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

how can i draw graphs like this with tikz?

functions: f(x) = x^2 + 0.25, f(x) = x^2 + 0.1 and f(x) = x^2 + 0.4

all them with the diagonal y=x.

[image]

I started with:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            domain = -.6:1,
            samples = 50,
            axis x line = center,
            axis y line = center,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            ticks = none
            ]
            \addplot[blue] {x*x + 0.25};
            \addplot[black] {x}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But don't know where i'm missing

Comment: You're definitely missing a semicolon at the end of the second \addplot at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were very close, only a few lines are missing. It's easy to change the function to show the other two plots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            domain = -.6:1,
            samples = 50,
            axis x line = center,
            axis y line = center,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            try min ticks = 10,
            scale only axis,
            ]
            \addplot[blue] {x*x + 0.25};
            \addplot[black] {x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If I may add a tiny cherry on top of @bmv's answer, you might benefit from declaring your function like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    % Declare the functions you need
    \tikzset{
        declare function={
            f(\x)=\x*\x + 0.25;
            g(\x)= f(\x) - 0.15;
            h(\x)= f(\x) + 0.15;
        }
    }
    
    \begin{axis}[
            domain = -.6:1,
            samples = 50,
            axis x line = center,
            axis y line = center,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            try min ticks = 10,
            scale only axis,
        ]
        % easy to resuse
        \addplot[blue] {f(x)};
        % \addplot[red] {g(x)};
        % \addplot[green] {h(x)};
        
        \addplot[black] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Is "declare function" specific to pgfplots or part of tikz?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I would say TikZ but someone more expert might confirm (?).

Comment: `/pgf/declare function=⟨function definitions⟩` (Section 96
Customizing the Mathematical Engine, pgfmanual https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). It means that `declare function` is a key that works when `pgf` or `tikz` is loaded.